# How to change background color and/or key color of Android soft keyboard without creating custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-custom-view

Currently, I am building app and depending on the app color the keyboard color should change automatically (dynamically).

I have found many examples of changing the color of keyboard but in all examples i found custom keyboard.

Can I change the background color and/or key color of Android soft keyboard without creating custom keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is no, you can not force all soft keyboard to change it's color because you want it act like that. You must create a keyboard and do it by yourself. 
Many keyboards provide change theme function but user must use keyboard settings to change the theme they want.
Hope this help.